# Using react components in string for react-intl-universal

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Trying to use Link within an i18n string but it doesn't read the Link component properly. How do you include react components in react-intl-universal?

language json file

```
{
  "somekey": "some<Link to={ link } somewhere </Link>"
}
```

javascript

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'

<Fragment>{ intl.getHTML('somekey', { link: `/somewhere` }) }</Fragment>
```

Comment: Change you json file to `{"somekey": "some<Link to={link} somewhere </Link>"}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a component in react-intl-universal getHTML() method. When you call this method, react-intl-universal create a span element and sets its inner HTML. So the translation that you return with intl.getHTML() is just a HTML string and not a component that will be translated into HTML by react.

You should breakdown your translation in 2 parts and write something like:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router'

<Fragment>
  {intl.get('contentBeforeLink')}
  <Link to="/somewhere">
    {intl.get('contentInsideLink')}
  </Link>
</Fragment>
```